# Сформировать post-запрос вручную

Tags: url, android, php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сформировать post-запрос с помощью ссылки. Я это делаю с помощью кода:

```
 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("version", String.valueOf(version)));
        JSONObject json = jsonFromURL.getJSONFromUrl(updateURL, params);
```

Мне нужно методом post отправить два поля tag="clean", ver="0".
Как вручную написать такой url?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "вручную написать такой url"?

Answer (score 1):

Вы что-то путаете. Если вы хотите поля в url вписать и послать - это get запрос:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
```

Для post-запроса надо так:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpParams httpParameters = httpClient.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 10 * 1000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout        (httpParameters, 10 * 1000);

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
// params - это ваш List<NameValuePair> с параметрами
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: @Jenya  Kirmiza, так сформулируйте правильно.

Comment: Уже не нужно, я просто затупил. Надо бы удалить этот дурацкий вопрос.